# Reverse image search engine

Tags: webapp-rec, search, images

Google, Bing and the others have image search option, but what I'm looking for is the reverse way: When I submit a photo, I want this web service to tell me in which places the image is located, and show me, if possible, the versions with higher resolution.

Does a web app like this exist?

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "Reverse image search engine"?

Comment: @Lazer: Here you are.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want to use [tineye](http://www.tineye.com/):

> TinEye is a reverse image search engine. It finds out where an image came from, how it is being used, if modified versions of the image exist, or if there is a higher resolution version.

Answer (score 5):

[**RevIMG**](http://www.revimg.com/) is another one:

> RevIMG is a reverse image search
>   engine.
>   Traditional image search
>   engine systems allow you to find
>   images starting from a text, RevIMG
>   works the opposite way: start the
>   search from an image and returns you
>   as result a list of links to web pages
>   where the image or similar ones are
>   contained.
>   Used in combination with a
>   traditional search engine like Google
>   search could make your search more
>   accurate.
>   RevIMG engine finds images
>   according to its matching algorithm
>   based on shape, dimensions and colors
>   likelihood.
>   The resulting links are
>   listed by matching percentage.

Answer (score 5):

Google have just launched their own reverse image search;

http://www.google.com/insidesearch/searchbyimage.html

> Now you can explore the web in an entirely new way by beginning your Google search with an image.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you find an image in Google Images, you can click "Similar Images" and Google will find images that look like the one you found.