# Image search server which finds all the same pages around the Internet

Tags: search, search-engine, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse image search engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/reverse-image-search-engine)

I have a picture, locally or with a URL. I would like to find all (well all known) places for its copies, maybe slightly modified, cropped or resized. Is there any search server like that?
P.S. This is not about artificial intelligence-based ones which look for a dog and find a car but with the same color and shape :)

Comment: Duplicate of [Reverse image search engine](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/reverse-image-search-engine).

Answer (score 0):

Try [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/).

> ## [TinEye is a reverse image search engine.](http://www.tineye.com/about)
>
> TinEye is a reverse image search engine. It finds out where an image came from, how it is being used, if modified versions of the image exist, or if there is a higher resolution version.