# Online similar images search engine

Tags: images, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse image search engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/reverse-image-search-engine)

Does anyone know of a search engine that allows you to upload an image and then find similar images on the web?

Comment: The title could probably be improved here. "With a twist" could mean anything, how about "Online similar images search engine" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Mike - I was struggling to think of a suitable title.

Answer (score 15):

### [Idée TinEye](http://ideeinc.com/products/tineye/)

"*What is TinEye?*"

> TinEye is the first image search
>   engine on the web to use image
>   identification technology. Given an
>   image to search for, TinEye tells you
>   where and how that image appears all
>   over the web—even if it has been
>   modified.

this is a small showcase of what results you might get when searching :

[alt text http://ideeinc.com/images/tineye_gallery/tineye-cloud-american-gothic.jpg](http://ideeinc.com/images/tineye_gallery/tineye-cloud-american-gothic.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/7-similarity-based-image-search-engines/8265/) compares several similarity-based image search engines. Only two of them are based on uploading an image:

- http://tineye.com/ (looks for copies of the same image, allowing for some modifications)
- http://labs.ideeinc.com/upload/ (looks for broadly similar images, based mainly on color)

Answer (score 1):

[Google similar images](http://similar-images.googlelabs.com/).

Not possible to upload an image though, but if it's somewhere online, chances are they already indexed it ;-)